# Issue with conditionally returning promise (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**Title of this question might needs editing**

Hi,
I have a method which either return an object or a promise. The function is as follows:

```
 function getAllTypes()
 {
   if(cache_hit)
   return from_cache;

   else
   {
    // db Query
    findAllTypes.then(function(result){
    return result;
    }
   }
}
```

This function will either returns a promise or a plain JS object depending on case. This is a utility function and will going to be used in many different places. I would like to keep its return type constant i.e either a promise or plain JS object(Which don't needs to be resolved) in both cases.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method might do something async then assume that it'll do it which means that it'll always return a promise, you can create a Promise from a single value with [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) i.e

```
function getAllTypes() {
  return cache_hit ? return Promise.resolve(from_cache) : findAllTypes()
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. :) Promise.resolve is standard JS?

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi yep http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve